# How to dynamically remove the whole Column from a single series HighCharts column graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is example for the simple column chart

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }]
});
```

I'm dynamically adding columns (points) like this

```
var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
chart.series[0].addPoint(["abc", 100]]);
```

So now I have to remove a column from the chart. I have dynamically added points by their names. So when I remove any particular added series name I need to remove that column from the chart.

When I add a new column (point) I create a button with its name with an 'x' mark so clicking that 'x' mark should remove that particular column from the chart. So all I have is its category name by which I need to remove it.

So I need to dynamically remove the column from the chart. Since it is all just a single series. I want the category to be removed with its respective data value. I'm not sure how to do that!

For example in the chart above I want to specifically remove 'Oct' from categories and its respective value from data '194.1'. And I just have its category value ('Oct'). Is that possible ?

I can't use this - chart.series[0].data[9].remove() because I don't know which index i'll have to remove since I only have its category value 'Oct'. Also it just removes the point from the chart and not the column as a whole (including its respective category value and reshifting the graph).

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which filters your data and your categories and updated your chart.

Example:

```
function removeCategoryAndData (chart, categoryName) {
  const { categories } = chart.xAxis[0]
  const categoryIndex = categories.indexOf(categoryName)
  const { data } = chart.series[0]

  // Filter data and categories
  const filteredData = data.map((p) => p.y).filter((v, i) => i !== categoryIndex)
  const filterdCategories = categories.filter((v, i) => i !== categoryIndex)

  // Update chart with filtered data and categories
  chart.update({ xAxis: { categories: filterdCategories }, series: { data: filteredData } })
}
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/yy9bhvq2/

Comment: It gives me this error - Uncaught TypeError: chart.update is not a function(…)

Comment: You are using old HC version. Update your highcharts version to newest one: http://code.highcharts.com/